# Is ArcSDE available with ArcGIS Desktop license?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, advanced-license-level

I have ArcGIS Desktop with the ArcInfo license level.

I want to know if I can configure ArcSDE, so that I can work with versioning of geodatabases?

---

The ArcInfo license level is now known as the Advanced license level (since ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop).

Comment: Version 10? Postgres for Windows is a 'free' option http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Installing_ArcSDE_for_PostgreSQL_on_Windows/002p0000000s000000/

Comment: I don't think you can authorize ArcSDE for Postgres through a desktop license, only SQL Express: See "How is ArcSDE technology included in ArcGIS?" under http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000007000000

Answer (score 6):

There is a [version of ArcSDE that is licensed with ArcGIS Desktop 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/install_guides/arcgis_desktop_or_arcgis_engine_microsoft_sql_server_express_installation_guide/index.html) - at the ArcInfo license level.  It works with Microsoft SQL Server Express.

This gives you the versioning and replication functionality of an ArcGIS Server based installation.  It is important to remember that the data stored here will only be accessed through the ArcGIS license on your workstation.  In fact, I think the databases created through this, have to be located on your local drive.

I have used this type of installation and it was very successful.  If you have a number of users working remotely on the same dataset, and need to control data editing and synchronization between them, this works very well if set up on each remote workstation.

Comment: Agreed. I use this very setup to manage a replica from our enterprise geodb for application-specific workflow management, complete with versions. Don't forget to set up backups and do regular maintenance!

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have ArcInfo single user license. Is it possible to create to local SDE's. Is it possible to do versioning and replication.